# Separating dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my current dilemma:

[image]

When I downloaded a csv file, I thought it would be separated into three separate columns for the date, Nouveaux cas and Cumulatif de cas, however that is not the case and all three are mushed together into one column and only separated by a ";". I only want the data related to Nouveaux cas, which is in the middle.

How do I proceed with this?

I tried to convert it to a tsv file and changing the separated data parts but it takes too much time. Is there an easier way to do this?

Code I used to read the file: `df=pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_csv("courbe.csv"))`
I manually downloaded the file.

Comment: Show your code so we can see how you imported your csv file.  The problems is that you need to set the separator to ";" as supposed to the default ","

Comment: @pakpe this is the code used to read it: df=pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_csv("courbe.csv")), I had manually downloaded the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pandas, change the separator like this:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('courbe.csv', sep=";")
```